# jointly distributed variables

Tags: probability, density-function

Suppose we are choosing a point inside the unit circle uniformly at random, that is the coordinate (X,Y ) of the point we choose is distributed with the joint probability density function   $f_{x,y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\pi} & x^{2}+y^{2}\leq1\\0 &else\end{cases}$

find the probability $P(Y>0.5|\mid X\mid+\mid Y\mid<1)$
I know that it is a continuous probability so it need to integrate it i know that p(y>0.5) is equal to $\int_{0.5}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}} \frac{1}{\pi}dx dy$ but I got no idea with |x|+|y|<1

Comment: Hint: Draw a figure of the unit disk $x^2+y^2<1$, the square $|x|+|y|<1$ in it, and the line $y=.5$. (The result, as a ratio of areas, should be $\frac18$.)

Comment: btw how to solve the inequality not by drawing

Comment: "btw" did you try to follow my suggestion? If you had, you would have a pretty clear idea of "how to solve the inequality not by drawing", as a bonus...

Comment: i tried it should be a rotated square but ii was wondering it is possible to solve it not by drawing